# Busqueda de datos

Tags: visual-c++

Es necisario hacer la busqueda de datos introduciendo el tipo de avión.

Esto es lo que tengo, pero siempre en el resultado sale que no existe el registro.

```
void Search(AEROFLOT* array)
{
    char plane[20];
    cout << "\nEnter type of airplane: "; 
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(plane);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (plane == array[i].plane)
        {
            cout << "\nDestination: " << pm[i].name << endl;
            cout << "Number of airplane: " << pm[i].number << endl;
            cout << "\n" << endl;
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "\nThere isn't an airplane of this type.\n" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Se que hay métodos de busqueda secuencial y binaria, pero quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer una sola busqueda directamente, ya que en el programa primero se introducen todos los datos, luego se ordenan en forma ascendente de acuerdo al numero de avión y por último se hace la busqueda.

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar cadenas en C++ no puedes usar operadores como ==, <, > u otros similares. C++ se basa en C, en el que los operadores de comparación solo se pueden usar para comparar los tipos básicos (como char, int, float, punteros y similares). Otros lenguajes como Java, C# y otros con sintaxis parecida corrigen estas deficiencias, pudiendo realizar comparaciones de tipos complejos con estos operadores.

Para realizar la comparación que tu quieres hacer tienes que usar alguna funcion como [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) y otras similares. Por ejemplo, la comparación que haces quedaría así con strcmp:

```
if (strcmp (plane, array[i].plane) == 0)
    {
        cout << "\nDestination: " << pm[i].name << endl;
        cout << "Number of airplane: " << pm[i].number << endl;
        cout << "\n" << endl;
        break;
    }
```

Otra opción sería usar alguna clase tipo String que sobrecargue el operador == para así poder hacer el código más intuitivo.

En cualquier caso te recomiendo que revises el código, ya que actualmente por cada avión que quieras buscar (y que exista en el array) te imprimirá un montón de textos "There isn't an airplane of this type".

Comment: Lo eh cambiado y sí, al ingresar un tipo de avión me da los datos correctos, pero vuelvo a repetir el mismo proceso, pero esta vez ingreso otro tipo de avión y me imprime "There isn't an airplane of this type". Como mencioné en la pregunta el programa realiza primero un ordenamiento y después la busqueda, creo que es por eso que con un tipo me da el resultado y con otro no.

Comment: @Neon. Esta pregunta está etiquetada como duplicada porque el error que comentas es exactamente el mismo. Revisa ese hilo y encontrarás la solución a tu problema. Tu función tiene dos errores (uno la comparación de cadenas y otro la gestión de los valores de retorno)

Comment: Tiene razón @eferion, las preguntas son muy similares. A falta de saber que es lo que haces en  resto del código, lo mas probable es que estés modificando alguna variable como el array que estás pasando como parametro, o la variable n, que supongo que es global y contiene el total de elementos del array. Esto último -por lo general- es una mala práctica de programación, ya que te puede llevar a errores difíciles de detectar. Mejor pasa ese valor por un parámetro, o ponle un nombre más descriptivo para no usarla sin querer en otro sitio.